# How can we get Position of an image and place an other image on that position with android

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to put a layer below the eye.

I want to know how can we get the exact position of an image and place another image on that position?

Excepted positions are:
top left, top center, top right
left center, center, right center
bottom left, bottom center, bottom right

Is this possible in `Android`?

Comment: Use the `getX()`, `getY()`, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods of `View` to calculate the required positions.

Answer (score 0):

Play Sevices help you do this stuff.

From Play Services 7.8 and onwards, It includes [Mobile Vision API's](https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction).

The Mobile Vision API has detectors that let you find objects in photos and video.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html